# How to convert Tasker app to native app?

Tags: java, c#, android, bluetooth

Using *Tasker for Android* (link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and a widget-composing tool, *Zooper* (link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.zooper.zwpro ) I have automated my Android phone to automatically register certain data whenever the phone enters or leaves certain WLAN-covered areas or connects/disconnects to certain BlueTooth devices.

The registered data is kept in simple Tasker-variables and a widget simply displays (some of) the contents of those variables to the user - it is really that simple.

Together this system works like an ever running background application with an always-updated (simple) user interface (the widget).

I am so happy with what this system does that I now want to convert the whole thing into a real, yet very tiny Android app that can be download and installed from Google Play.

However, I never developed an Android app before (and not an IOS app either!). But being a professional C# developer (and former C++ developer) for Windows desktop applications and Windows services for many years now, I feel confident that I can also learn how to make such a simple Android app, even if it involves programming languages with which I’m not so confident by now (Java for example).

What I need is a few directions to get me started the right way:

- Which tools do I need for making such a simple app?
- Can it be done in Visual Studio, or do I need to use Eclipse or
  Xamarin?
- Can it be done in C# or must it be done in Java?
- Do I need to buy licenses for development tools (other than Visual
  Studio) or can it be done with free software?

How would you go about the whole thing?

Any input will be much appreciated!

Comment: Download Eclipse with the Android SDK.  All free.  Follow some tutorials.  That's pretty much all you need to get started.  Java is not difficult to learn.  It's just syntax.  But you need to learn how the system works to get an app compiled and running.

Comment: I haven’t done this, but I think you can use the [Tasker App Factory](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.appfactory&hl=en) for this ([guide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/appcreation.html) on the Tasker website).

Comment: Easiest way to do it is Android Studio, which is a free download.  THere are tools for doing it C#, but they cost money.  Doing Java for an experiences C# dev shouldn't be too hard.  You can do it all without costing money, but if you want to publish on Google Play there is a 1 time fee to sign up, it used to be $25.  THat's a lifetime membership, not a yearly fee like iOS.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, I will gat started with Eclipse and study some examples and get going that way.